# How to get Low Heart Rate notification from ios Healthkit app using swift?

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, apple-watch, healthkit

I'm using the following Swift code.

```
let lowHREventType = HKObjectType.categoryType(forIdentifier: .lowHeartRateEvent)
let lowHREventQuery = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: lowHREventType, predicate: nil, limit: 30, sortDescriptors: [sortByTime]) { (query, tmpResult, error) -> Void in
            
            if error != nil {
                
                // Handle the error in your app gracefully
                return
                
            }
            
            if let result = tmpResult {
                
                for item in result {
                    if let sample = item as? HKCategorySample {
                        print("Healthkit Low: \(sample.startDate) \(sample.endDate) - value: \(sample.value)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I get no result from the query.
Please advise me on how to resolve this issue.

Comment: You define the query here but you do not start it. Do you have an instance of HKHealthStore to execute the query? I copied your code and it works fine for me.

Comment: but I can't generate an alert from the apple watch. I also set high = 100 and low = 50 in the watch app. can you guide me on how to generate an alert so I check first in the health app

Comment: post a new question. show some code. maybe you need to start with simpler problems till you see how the code works.

Comment: No @johnelemans, I need just first to see high or low heart rate notifications in the Apple Health app. after that this code works for fetch notification via health kit.
I need to know how high and low heart notification to the Apple Health app.
and how I produce alert